# Determining which maps are isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

1) Let $G=G'=\{(a,b)\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a, b \ne 0\}$ with group operation $(a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,b_1b_2)$. Let $\phi (a,b) = (b^{-1}, ab^2)$.

My solution:

1-1: Suppose $(b_1^{-1},a_1b_1^2)=(b_2^{-1},a_2b_2^2)$. Then $b_1^{-1} = b_2^{-1}$ will imply $b_1 = b_2$ since they are non-zero reals and thus can be represented as equal fractions. Since  $b_1 = b_2$, $a_1b_1^2 = a_2b_2^2$ implies $a_1 = a_2$ since we can divide out the b terms.

onto: Take $(b_1^{-1},a_1b_1^2) \in G'$. Since $b_1^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\ne 0$ there exists a $b_1 \in G$ such that $b_1^{-1} = \frac{1}{b_1}$, which is obviously in $G$ since it $b$ is non zero, Similarly it can be shown that $a_1b_1^2$ corresponds to $a_1,b_1 \in G$.

Im unsure how to show how $\phi$ is order preserving however.

2) Let $G = \left\{\left.\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}\right| \,a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a^2\ne b^2\right\}$ Let $G' = \left\{(c,d)\mid c,d \in \mathbb{R},c,a \ne 0\right\}$. Prove $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic.

My solution:
Defining the isomorphism, we can clearly see that $\phi(G) = (a+b,a-b)$ since $c,d$ are its corresponding eigenvalues.

1-1: If we fix two points in $G'$ we can clearly see they have to correspond to the same element in $G$ since both elements are non zero.

onto: Im having a bit of trouble describing how an element in $G'$ corresponds to an element in $G$

Order-preserving: Let $(c_1,d_1), (c_2,d_2) \in G'$ since they correspond to the eigenvalues of two matrices in $G$, and $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, we can clearly see that the operation preserves order.

3) Let G = $\left\{\left.\begin{bmatrix} 1-x & x \\-x & 1+x \end{bmatrix}\right|\, x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ under matrix multiplication. Prove that G is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

4)Let $G$ and $G'$ be groups. Let $Z(G)$ and $Z(G')$ be the center of the corresponding groups. Suppouse that $\phi : G \to G'$. Prove that $\phi(Z(G)) = Z(G')$

Im stumped with the last two especially, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: "Order preserving" is not what you should be trying to check. You should be deciding whether $\phi$ is a homomorphism, i.e. $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$ for all $g,h \in G$,

Comment: @DerekHolt oddly enough my book describes order-preserving as having the same property of a homomorphism and requires that we check to ensure it the same way as we would check for a homomorphism

Comment: @DerekHolt it describes as preserving order if $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$

Comment: @DerekHolt so is it the same thing? im a bit confused

Comment: @bobdylan Say you've got a homomorphism, that is, a function $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ for which $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ holds.  Say that $g\in G$ has order $n$.  Note that $$\phi(g^2)=\phi(g)\phi(g)=\phi(g)^2,$$ $$\phi(g^3)=\phi(g)\phi(g)\phi(g)=\phi(g)^3,$$ and so on.  Then $$\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n=\phi(\text{id}_G)=\text{id}_H.$$  So the order of $\phi(g)$ divides $n$.

Comment: @bobdylan An *isomorphism*, however, is a homomorphism that is also bijective.  In particular, this means that *only* $\text{id}_G$ is mapped to $\text{id}_H$.  (Do you understand why?)  So in this case, since $g^k\not= \text{id}_G$ for any $k<n$, we also have that $\phi(g^k)=\phi(g)^k\not= \text{id}_H$.  But the previous calculation still works: $\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n=\text{id}_H$.  So the order of $\phi(g)$ is $n$, the same as the order of $g$.  That's what it means when it says that isomorphisms are order preserving.

Comment: Every isomorphism is order preserving, but it is not true that every order preserving bijection is an isomorphism. so the two properties are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, a word on intuition.  If $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism, that means you should think about $G$ and $H$ as being the *same group*.  Saying that two groups are isomorphic is kind of like saying they are equal.  The elements may not be the same, but they *work* the same in every way that matters to group theorists.  (So $\#4$ for example should feel natural - they're the same group, so they should have the same center.)

*Hints*:

1. Like Derek Holt said, what you're missing is a proof that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$.
2. You've got the right idea, just clean up your proof.
3. Map $\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1-x & x \\
    -x & 1+x
   \end{array}
   \right)$ to $x$ and prove that $$\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1-x & x \\
    -x & 1+x
   \end{array}
   \right)\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1-y & y \\
    -y & 1+y
   \end{array}
   \right)=\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    1-x-y & x+y \\
    -x-y & 1+x+y
   \end{array}
   \right).$$  You can see that this is going to be isomorphic to the *additive* group of $\mathbb{R}$.
4. If $\phi$ is a homomorphism and $ab=ba$, is it true that $\phi(ab)=\phi(ba)$?  That part just gives you $\phi(Z(G))\subseteq Z(G')$.  Bijectivity of $\phi$ gives you the reverse inclusion.